# Will this helicopter fly?

Tags: aircraft-performance

There is a helicopter that can lift 1000 kg.

I'm going to suspend a very large 250 kg square piece of plywood underneath it, wider than the rotors.

On the first try it will be attached directly to the skids.

On the second try, it will be 20 feet below the skids.

Will it fly?  Which one flys better.  Why?

Comment: You’ll survive longer in the first scenario.   If you even manage to get off the ground in the second scenario and start moving that plywood will swing up behind and I predict a swift and expensive end to that helicopter.

Answer (score 2):

[image][Pic source](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-69217e1e6df0d8093a932bce0a76c503-c)

The first try may not result in a lift-off, the second try has a much higher probability of being able to fly.

1. Large piece of plywood directly attached to the skids: the rotor downwash blows down on the plywood, thereby negating the rotor thrust. Like a person in a cockpit pushing on the sidewalls, or a person in a sailing boat blowing air into the main sail with an air blower: no external thrust is generated. That is, if the plywood is flat.
2. Plywood attached to 20 ft rope: Now the helicopter can lift off at least 20 ft. And then again the rotor downwash will be blowing on the helicopter  structure itself, but this time a larger part of the downwash may actually be free to bypass the plywood and create useful thrust. In the pic above on the right hand side it may be seen that some of the outside downwash still has some vertical lift vectorial components.

Comment: It’s reasonable to assume that once the plywood leaves the ground there will be significant turbulence and buffeting under it.   I’d be surprised if it didn’t oscillate with considerable energy.

Comment: @Koyovis maybe the better question would be if a fan blew into a sail, which way would the boat go.  If one removed the big "airmover"  blades and put in, for example, Daedelus props, I think the fan would win.

Comment: I second what @Frog wrote, I bet it will end badly.

Comment: @Jpe61 yeah probably.